# Reversing the input of a transistor

Tags: transistors, dc, charger, 12v, 5v

I want to detect if a 12V DC line has power or not. I want the transistor to work like this: **If pin 2 has 5-12V, pin 1 and 3 should be disconnected and should stop the flow of 5V 2A across pin 1 and 3. Also similarly if no voltage is being applied on pin 2, pin 1 and 3 should be connected** 
[image: transistor]

I don't know much about circuits, components and how they work. So please tell a very simple solution, I only want component level solutions, not circuit level. Also, as I'm not a professional, I don't know where to buy components, so I salvage components from chargers, CFL lights, old phones, Bluetooth speakers, calculator s etc. As a result I only know few transistor name. Right now i only have 13005 transistor. Please tell me if this transistor can be used as reverse transistor. Lastly sorry for  not knowing basic electronic facts.

Comment: you're not going to get a solution to this that isn't "circuit level".

Comment: @Hearth Already got one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 12 V line has to have 12 V relative to some other point in your circuit. Normally this is the battery or supply negative and called 'ground' or GND and is the point from which we measure other voltages in the circuit. You would usually connect the black multimeter lead to ground when taking DC voltage measurements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBmxsK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two circuits.*

- Figure 1a is the simplest. If RLY1, a 5 V relay, is de-energised then 1 and 3 are connected. If the relay is energised by a 5 V signal on 2 then 1 and 3 are disconnected. The problem is that applying 12 V would burn out a 5 V relay.
- Figure 1b solves this problem by using a 12 V relay in front of the 5 V relay. At 5 V RLY3 will energise and disconnect 1 and 3. At 12 V (and more likely somewhere between 9 and 12 V) RLY2 will be energised, disconnect RLY3's coil so that it doesn't overheat and again 1 and 3 will be disconnected.

The circuit is crude but might be good enough for your application - which you haven't explained.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot to understand this. As It solves my problem, but where can i get this rlys? Also for covid-19 all electronics markets are shutdown. So can I find any relay in any old electronics? Like mobile, desktop power supply, led lights??

Comment: Also should I post the full project?? So you understand better, what i want to do.

Comment: All the major electronics suppliers are still in business and shipping. 12 V relays are used in cars. 5 V relays will be harder to find. If it solves your problem there is no need to provide more details.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I'll try to find one.